# Php classname

Tags: php, wordpress

здравствуйте, пишу на пхп вордпресс темы плагины и очень хочу правильно решить вот какую проблемку:

для работы создал дополнительный статический класс например class Additional, и если в проекте подключены два моих плагина, и в обоих есть этот класс, это вызывает ошибку, т.е. я пока пишу в разных проектах Additional001, Additional002..

возможности Additional используются в другом рабочем классе например: Additional001::func();

я так понимаю для решения этого я так и должен дальше декларировать Additional001, Additional002.., только в рабочем классе я должен создать некую instance для него..
может быть в конструкторе рабочего класса я должен создать переменную этого рабочего класса, которая будет ссылаться на Additional001 например, и  в рабочем классе в любом месте я смог бы испльзовать что то вроде $this, self -> AD

надеюсь понятно пояснил и собственно вопрос: как правильно это решается? без неймспейсов

Comment: Как на счет сделать Additional singleton-ом? http://ideone.com/JLhOSP

Comment: на глаза не попадался.., сейчас почитаю спасибо

Comment: тогда из другого класса я смогу обращаться к Additional через self::instance()->func() ?

Comment: Немного подругому:

    Additional::instance()->func()

Comment: спасибо буду думать как лучше

Comment: > без неймспейсов

неймспейсы были созданы как раз для того, чтобы решить эту проблему. Можно использовать старую конвенцию с неймспейсами в именах классов (`PrettyPagination_Templating_Additional` - класс Additional секции Templating плагина PrettyPagination) или явно задавать уникальные имена (по факту, то же самое - `PrettyPaginationTemplateHelper`). Я бы рекомендовал все-таки прибегнуть к неймспейсам (PSR-4), потому что это позволит реализовать нижеописанную фабрику на уровне автозагрузчика и оператора `new`.